# Visual Studio Team Services & website projects

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have been trying to get my personal website project on VSTS. I have been able to get it up there however when I look at the file explorer I only see the .sln. I have been able to add other files and it will show up in the file explorer however when I run via Visual Studio it either won't compile or be unable to access the other html pages.

[image: Solution Explorer Example]

In the example above I'd see HTMLPage1.html and MySite.sln (along with the .gitignores). But I wouldn't be able to access the HTMLPage1.html from of my files in the solution.

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio and appreciate any assistance!

Comment: Have you added a reference to a project that's *outside* the folder the solution is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, the default behavior in VS puts the website in one folder (%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\**Websites**\YourWebsite) and the solution file in a different one  (%UserProfile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\**Projects**\YourWebsite).  If your git repo contains the solution file, it probably doesn't contain the website folder.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to:

- Open the website folder in Windows Explorer
- Remove the website project from the solution in VS
- Copy the website folder to the solution folder in Windows Explorer
- Add Existing Website and give it the new folder location within your git repo.

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out what you meant but it works now! Thank you!